# change font color to all <li> tags

Tags: html, css

Basically I want to change the color of all the `li` tags to white from the code shown below

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">    
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"   href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

I tried to add a CSS for the li tags

```
nav.navbar nav.navbar-inverse div.container-fluid ul.nav ul.navbar-nav   
ul.navbar-right li a {
color: white;
}
```

but it not changing the color to white. Please help.

Comment: you will have to use some commas

Comment: did u write  just               li {color:white}                          in your css

Comment: you are missing closing div and nav tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if u write  `li{color:white}` then u just change the list point icon not text because there are anchors in them so u should write
`li a{color:white}` to make all li text white

Answer (score 6):

No need to this incredibly long and wrong selector, just add this :

```
nav.navbar li a {
  color: white;
}
```

You can change the links color, not the `li` color.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhcoo7e3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors are separated by `,`. Separating it with whitespace will make hierarchical selection.

```css
nav.navbar,
nav.navbar-inverse,
div.container-fluid,
ul.nav,
ul.navbar-nav,
ul.navbar-right li a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your selector is specific to the point that it's incorrect.

`.navbar-right li {
    color: white;
}`

should do it